# Task WhenAll with multiple taks that all have their own tasks

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I want to make a call to Task.WhenAll and wait a number of Tasks that each have their own subtasks, and I was wondering if I am doing it correctly in my implementation, It seems a bit verbose and I was wondering if there is a shorter version for it.

```
public async Task ChangeNotificationsDispatchTimeAsync(string userId, DateTime utcDateTimeToSend)
{
    IList<TNotificationEntity> notifications =
        await _notificationsTable.GetRowsByPartitionKeyAndRowKeyAsync(ToTicks(_now), userId, QueryComparisons.GreaterThanOrEqual);
    await Task.WhenAll(
        notifications.Select(notification =>
        {
            return new Task(() =>
            {
                _notificationsTable.DeleteRowAsync(notification.PartitionKey, notification.RowKey);
                notification.PartitionKey = ToTicks(utcDateTimeToSend);
                _notificationsTable.InsertRowAsync(notification);
            });
        }));        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to Start those tasks. Also, you can make your lamba async, and use await within the body. (assuming DeleteRowAsync/InsertRowAsync return Task)

I'd suggest using ConfigureAwait(false) if you don't need to recapture the SynchronizationContext.

```
IList<TNotificationEntity> notifications =
    await _notificationsTable.GetRowsByPartitionKeyAndRowKeyAsync(ToTicks(_now), userId, QueryComparisons.GreaterThanOrEqual)
    .ConfigureAwait(false);
await Task.WhenAll(
    notifications.Select(notification =>
    {
        return Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            await _notificationsTable.DeleteRowAsync(notification.PartitionKey, notification.RowKey).ConfigureAwait(false);
            notification.PartitionKey = ToTicks(utcDateTimeToSend);
            await _notificationsTable.InsertRowAsync(notification).ConfigureAwait(false);
        });
    })).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

That is, if your intent is to run many of those *notifications* in a separate ThreadPool thread. That means you probably have multiple Delete/Insert going in parallel. Is that your intent? Is it possible that *GetRowsByPartitionKeyAndRowKeyAsync* will return lots of data?

Would it be possible to create a more batch based approach where you pass the *notifications* and will execute within a single connection to the DB?